# There are two types of customers in a fast food chain....

Tags: probability

There are two types of customers in a fast food chain W. Customers of the first type order burger+drink, and it takes a cashier $30$ seconds to take this order.  Customers of the second type order only coffee, and it takes $15$ seconds to take the order.  It is known that $30\%$ of customers are of the first type and $70\%$ are of the second type.  What is the probability that the cashier will be able to take orders from $5$ random customers in $2$ minutes or less?

my solution...

There are $2$ scenarios in which the cashier will fail...

scenario 1: $5$ burgers+drinks $= .3^5 = .00243$

scenario 2: $4$ burgers+drinks 1 coffee $= .3^4 \cdot .7 = .0567$

$1 - (.00243 + .0567) = 0.94087$

I HAVE A FEELING this isn't correct

What exactly am I missing? Do I need to be concerned with order or anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation for scenario 2 misses the fact that it could be any one of the customers that just orders coffee.  Look up the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Comment: would the second scenario be something like..... P(1 coffee purchased) = (5 choose 1) * .7 * (.3)^4 = 0.02835 ?

Comment: Exactly...............

Comment: awesome thank you.. and for secnario one it works out but it looks like P(0 coffee purchased) = (5 choose 0) * .7^0 * .3^5

Comment: but otherwise adding those two and subtracting from 1 is the correct solution?

Comment: Yes it is.  The $5 \choose 0$ is $1$ which is why your scenario 1 was correct.